# Error 500 when use axios call service on Linux enviroment but working on local on Windows

Tags: java, reactjs, axios

I use react for frontend and Java for Backend.
When i call service on local. It'work but error 500 on test enviroment(linux)

React (Frontend) :

```
const getDatas = async () => {
        const config = {
            method: 'get',
            url: process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + 'get-all-to-acc-transaction',
            withCredentials: true,
            params: {
                type: '01',
                objectType: null,
            },
        }

        const result = await axios(config);
        if (result.data.code == '00') {
            //todo somethings
        }
        
        }
```

Java (Backend)

```
@GetMapping("/get-all-acc-transaction-combobox")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> getAllAccTransactionCombobox(@RequestParam String type) {
        return txnManualService.getAllAccTransactionCombobox(type);
    }
```

Url API local:
http://localhost:2998/project-test/get-all-acc-transaction-combobox?type=1

Url API test environment:
http://10.23.8.187:2998/project-test/get-all-acc-transaction-combobox?type=1

When change url test enviroment to:
[http://10.23.8.187:2998/project-test/get-all-acc-transaction-combobox?type='1'](http://10.23.8.187:2998/project-test/get-all-acc-transaction-combobox?type=%271%27). It work.
So where did I go wrong? I think the backend is still receiving the parameter type is string and the axios passing is numeric so the error. Thanks everyone :(((

Comment: Error code 500 means internal server error. Please check the backend logs on linux server for details information about the error.

Comment: I have a log, but there is no log related to this problem.